# ERR_ABORTED 404 error when running https:/username/github.io/index.html

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I have created a Github page and have followed all the steps. So my Github webpage is https://username.github.io. I have an index.html file. The index.html file has several .js files. I have added all those .js files to the repository. There is no directory structure, i.e., all the .js files are present along with the index.html. In the index.html I'm calling the .js files as `<script src="main.js"></script>`. However when I go to my Chrome browser, the .js files are not read it seems and I get the following error when I check the console.

`GET https://username.github.io/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

I tried clearing the cache/cookies and made sure that "Javascript is allowed" by going to the Chrome settings. I tried searching for an answer and couldn't find one that solves this. Can somebody please help? Much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it seems like adding a / to the path makes it work. I.e., I have now ```<script src="/main.js"></script>```. Seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a late answer, but I was experimenting with Vue and faced (and struggled + wasted a lot of time with) the same issue.

Whether the .js and .css files are in the /(root) along with index.html or not, the RCA is as follows -

> GET https://username.github.io/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

should actually be

```
GET https://username.github.io/<REPO_NAME>/main.js
```

or in my case,

```
GET https://username.github.io/<REPO_NAME>/js/<js-file>.js
```

SOLUTION -

This path can be fixed either directly in the index.html OR Setting the publicPath in vue.config.js before building as suggested in [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-your-vue-app-to-github-pages-897136799e19) blog helped.

*NOTE*: Since the repository is named same as the account name, adding the "/" to the path works